# C++ namespace declerations inside a C++ class

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have the following RESTClient class that I am planning to implement using `boost.beast`. I have the following namespaces declared in the header.

```
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
namespace net = boost::asio;
using tcp = boost::asio::ip::tcp;
```

However I don't want to pollute the global namespace. I want the namespce to be declared inside the class. I tried the technique declared here [C++ mistakes avoid global namespaces](https://www.acodersjourney.com/top-10-c-header-file-mistakes-and-how-to-fix-them/).
That doesn't seem to help. What is an elegant way to bring the above namespace decleration to inside the class

```
class RESTClient {
public:

    explicit RESTClient(std::shared_ptr<net::io_context> ioc, std::shared_ptr<Logger> logger, std::shared_ptr<Configuration> config);

    virtual ~RESTClient();

private:
    std::shared_ptr<Logger> m_logger;

};
```

Answer (score 0):

The language simply doesn't allow you to use `using directive` for a namespace inside a class. Therefore a code like the following is rejected by the compiler. Even using a namespace alias is within class scope is an error.

```
class MyClass {
  using namespace std;  // error
  namespace s = std; // error
};
```

The most likely solution for you would be to declare namespace (`using namespace` declaration) or namespace aliasing within function scope.

```
struct X {
  void foo() {
    using namespace std;
    cout << "foo\n"; // without namespace
  }

  void bar() {
    std::cout << "bar\n"; // using fully qualified name
  }
};
```

Comment: this does apply to header files

Comment: @liv2hak `using directive` in header file should be avoided in any case at file level. In function level in a header it doesn't do much harm as long as the other names inside that function have any collisions with the imported namespace.

Comment: but how do I avoid it. you have declared the namespace in the function scope. I have parameters that use types defined in the boost namespace.

Comment: For parameters you use the fully qualified name. Inside the function you can use the `using directive`, if you're sure it won't cause any name collisions. In cpp files you don't need to be this restrictive.